# AJAX: only error callback is been fired

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I have declared `success` and `error` callbacks, but in case of status code `200` also it calls error callback only.

I have been making curl call to some other `php` file too inside `registry.php`.

Here what i tried:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST"
  ,data: {
    action: "blah"
    ,mobileNo: that.mobNo
    ,token: that.key
  }
  ,url: "http://90.8.41.232/localhost/registry.php"
  ,cache: false
  ,dataType: "json"
  ,success: function (response) {
    console.log("success");
  }
  ,error: function () {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

I have read in documentation that we don't have to call success callback explicitly, hope it's correct.

Any idea how to call success callback when it is 200 status code.

**RESPONSE**
hope this will help, this I copied from chrome console, not printed by console.log().

```
bort: (statusText)
always: ()
complete: ()
done: ()
error: ()
fail: ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ()
getResponseHeader: (key)
overrideMimeType: (type)
pipe: ()
progress: ()
promise: (obj)
readyState: 4
responseText: "{"success":"Mobile No 9535746622 is approved"}      {"report":true}"
setRequestHeader: (name,value)
state: ()
status: 200
statusCode: (map)
statusText: "OK"
success: ()
then: ()
```

Comment: Your code looks right, is the answer from the server valid json?

Comment: Are you sure `http://90.8.41.232/localhost/registry.php` is not a cross domain data access? if it is then you might need to enable cors at registry.php by providing specific headers and also you need to check for `jsonp` for cross domain data access.

Comment: The error function takes three arguments. Look at them, they will probably tell you what is wrong. The JavaScript error console may also show you errors. The Net tab of your developer tools will let you confirm if you have got a 200 OK status code in the response, have you checked it?

Comment: Yes, I've checked all those things @Quentin

Comment: @PJ1405 — And what do the arguments to the error function say? Given your edits I'd expect it to tell you about a JSON parsing error.

Comment: are you using curl call in registry.php ?

Comment: Yes, does it makes difference ?

Comment: I don't think the response from your server is valid JSON...looks like 2 separate JSON objects. As an experiment, try removing `dataType: "json"` and use `$.parseJSON()` in your success callback...I think you'll find that it fails to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are making a `curl` call to some other `php`, what happens is whenever you make `curl` call you have to return the response of the `curl` to the client. So to transfer the `return` value of `curl` call, you have to set an option `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);`.
This will sort your problem. Hope so.

Answer (score 2):

First, checkout the real error you get (not certain you really get a 200 status ?)

```
error: function (err) {
  console.error("error");
  console.log(err);
  console.log(err.stack);
  throw err;
}
```

Show us the resulting log please.

Comment: i have added response object, there status code `200` n `ok`.

Comment: Please put the console.log(err); Its like that you will see the thrown error details

Answer (score -2):

I did that a few weeks ago and for me it works if I call it like

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    data: { action: "blah", mobileNo: that.mobNo, token: that.key },
    url: "http://90.8.41.232/localhost/registry.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: json,
})
.success (function (data, status, jqxhr)
{
    // do your stuff
})
.error (function(x, status, jqxhr) 
{
    // handle your errors
});
```